# Bootstrap 4 downloaded files not working. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, file-structure

I've created a site with Bootstrap 4. I downloaded all the files necessary for Bootstrap to work, and for some strange reason, it's not working. When I use the CDN version of Bootstrap, everything works just fine. Am I missing something?  You can view the site [here.](http://vpay.cl/test/index.html)

This is my file structure for JS

[image: This is my file structure for the JS files.]

This is my file structure for the CSS files
[image]

Comment: are you directly accessing the file? you should use MAMP

Comment: @DanOrlovsky yes, I want to physically include them in my page. You can view the code by visiting the site www.vpay.cl/test/index.html

Comment: @AbdulRahmanASamad I want to direct access the files. What is MAMP?

Comment: @Paula it seems to be working for me.

Comment: It seems working on my end also, try refreshing the cache of your browser

Comment: it's working here? Oh MAMP is just a local development server that you can use. https://www.mamp.info/en/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be including the Bootstrap CSS correctly using a relative path - css/bootstrap.min.css.

It appears you are using the CDN version of the Bootstrap JS and want to use the copy on your own server. You can include it in a similar way to that of the CSS above.

i.e.

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If you have any further questions, comment below and I will help further.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should have specified that the part that is not working is the toggle menu when the site goes to mobile view.  When I use relative paths to the JS files, and I click on the menu, it doesn't open. If I use CDN bootstrap, it works. Are my files in the correct order?

Comment: Yes, they are in the correct order. The difference between the Download and the CDN is the Download does not include JQuery and Popper. Leave the JQuery and Popper lines as they are and in the third line (Bootstrap) use the <script> tag line in the answer above.